# Illustrator CS6 tracingoptions maxColors not working?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am using extendscript to create a script for CS6.

I have referred to the PDF here: http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/illustrator/scripting/cs6/Illustrator-Scripting-Reference-JavaScript.pdf

I am having some problems setting maxcolor on tracingoptions.

```
sel = app.activeDocument.selection;
if (sel.length > 0){
    newItem = sel[0].duplicate();
    var traceobj = newItem.trace();
    var opt = traceobj.tracing.tracingOptions;
    opt.maxColors = 16;
    traceobj.tracing.tracingOptions = opt;
}
```

It traces with 100 colours regardless of value set on maxColors.

If I dump opt before applying

```
opt.maxColors = 16
```

There is no `maxColors` value in the object.

`Tracingmodetype` is

```
TracingModeType.TRACINGMODECOLOR
```

If I do:

```
traceobj.tracing.tracingOptions.loadFromPreset("16 Colors");
```

It loads the preset for '16 colors', but I do not want to load the preset as I will be setting other options and also want the option of setting the maximum colours to other amounts.

Is there any reason why `maxColors` would not work or exist in `tracingoptions` when I dump the default values?

Comment: "Maximum number of colors allowed for tracing **when TracingColorTypeValue is TracingLimitedColor**" -- my emphasis.

Comment: Tried this value as well with no luck. Starting to think this is a bug with Illustrator.